# Android compose Modifier extension does not work with testTagsAsResourceId

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, appium

We need to add id so people from QA can use Appium Inspector, this works:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .semantics { this.testTagsAsResourceId = true }
        .testTag("someId"),
    text = "Something"
)
```

The problem is repeating those two lines on every composable that needs it, is tedious

```
.semantics { this.testTagsAsResourceId = true }
.testTag("someId")
```

So creating an extension for `Modifier` could be the solution:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun Modifier.setTagAndId(tag: String): Modifier = composed {
    semantics { this.testTagsAsResourceId = true }
    testTag(tag)
}
```

When running Appium Inpsector the ids are not there, if instead replace the extension for the two lines directly in the composable, I can see the ids.

Writing the extension in other way does not work neither

```
fun Modifier.setTagAndId(tag: String): Modifier {
    semantics { this.testTagsAsResourceId = true }
    testTag(tag)
    return this
}
```

The above introduces another problem, the `testTag` is not found by Espresso, so that is another reason to discard it.

Changing the experimental annotation to propagate and then opt-in in the composable neither works:

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
fun Modifier.setTagAndId(tag: String): Modifier {
...
}
```

Reading the `composed` documentation the first argument is the `InspectorInfo`, so I tried to abide to that:

```
fun Modifier.setTagAndId(tag: String): Modifier = composed(
    inspectorInfo = {
        name = "TestTagsAsResourceId" //got the name from testTagsAsResourceId file
        value = tag
    }
) {
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I have created extensions for `Modifier` using `composed` as well, so after all the attempts I don't understand why is not working with `testTagsAsResourceId`.

How to create an extension for `Modifier` to set the `semantics` property `testTagsAsResourceId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
fun Modifier.setTagAndId(tag: String): Modifier {
    return this
        .semantics { this.testTagsAsResourceId = true }
        .testTag(tag)
}
```

Btw you don't need to set `testTagsAsResourceId` on every resource that you need a testTag. Only on the root composable (And dialogs) see https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/semantics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.semantics.SemanticsPropertyReceiver).testTagsAsResourceId()

Comment: Having the extension allows application on migration process to add the id for multiple `ComposeView` XML tags, a valid point thanks for pointing it out on the documentation as well.
I see my error now! My code was equivalent to `val unused = this.semantics` and then `return this.testTag` so `unused` was never used, thanks (modifier is copied not mutate).